# Concept of <!doctype>..Please explain in plain english

Tags: html

I have learnt HTML recently, but not able to clear my concept about `<!doctype>`. Please explain `<!doctype>` in detail in plain English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's up, DOCTYPE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414891/whats-up-doctype)

Comment: You may find [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076432/why-do-i-need-a-doctype-what-does-it-do) useful.

Answer (score 1):

It;s just the information for web browser about the opened document. Web browser needs to know what kind of document it opens and how to 'read' and display it properly.

Answer (score 0):

`<! doctype>` tag is where your code declares to the browser what kind of standard rest of the code using. There are some kinds of html, like

- HTML 5
- HTML 4.01 Transitional
- HTML 4.01 Frameset
- XHTML 1.0 Strict
- XHTML 1.0 Transitional
- XHTML 1.0 Frameset
- XHTML 1.1

Browsers used to treat codes differently. Its not that much important now but writing a good structured code doesn't hurt anyone.

More information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp).