# purecss pure-menu-item doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

This menu code is the first example in http://purecss.io/menus/.

Yet it works bad :(

Each `<li>` item stays a screenful of distance one another. If you scroll down you see the other items.

But it works in the purecss.io/menus page. I don't know why.

(Here when you run it works fine too… You have to create an html document with this code, then it fails…)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pure-menu">
    <span class="pure-menu-heading">Yahoo Sites</span>

    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Flickr</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Messenger</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Sports</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Finance</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-heading">More Sites</li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Games</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">News</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">OMG!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I've seen that `pure-menu-item` has a `height: 100%`, which I think is a bit strange. Is this the problem?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but it seems to be working fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/yr4hgvr1/.

Comment: Yeap. I was adding as a snippet and it works fine here too. But if you put only it in a html document it fails… I don't know why

Comment: Are you loading any other CSS styles?

Comment: nope, this is the exact code I'm running

Comment: I tried running it in a html document and got the same error... That's so strange...

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem, can you post your complete HTML file again?

Comment: Ok. The snippet has the whole code now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, you need to declare a doctype, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pure-menu">
      <span class="pure-menu-heading">Yahoo Sites</span>

      <ul class="pure-menu-list">
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Flickr</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Messenger</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Sports</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Finance</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pure-menu-heading">More Sites</li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Games</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">OMG!</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) for more information on how to structure your HTML file.

Comment: Alright, worked. Awesome! Can you tell why the heights fail then? Why is the doctype related to this styling?

Comment: The doctype tells the browser which version of HTML you are using.  If you leave it out entirely the browser will use quirksmode which can cause all kinds of problems with your code. For more info see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6076432/2126792 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with the usage of pure-menu-item. It has indeed a height of `100%`. I overwrote that height by adding `style="height:20pt"` to the div where the menu was in. I used a horizontal menu btw.

Answer (score 0):

I added in my custom app.css to override pure css

```
.pure-menu-item { height: inherit; }
```