# <!doctype html> is messing up <li> element

Tags: html, css

Without `<!doctype html>` it is shown correctly:

[image: Before doctype]

With `<!doctype html>` li element is moved to the left side:

[image: With doctype]

Same result in Firefox and IE.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="content-wrapper">
<li>Title - <a href='#'>[Edit]</a> | <a href='#'>[Delete]</a></li>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

h1, h2, h3{
    margin: 0px;
}  

#content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding-top: 12px; 
}
```

How could I avoid this?

Comment: Just to be sure, you should use `<!doctype html>`, note the `!`.

Comment: you must use `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Fix your html, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076432/why-do-i-need-a-doctype-what-does-it-do) why you use it

Comment: What HTML are you using?

Comment: @KarlBrown It's added to the post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

`<li>` items are not allowed to be child elements of a `<div>`. They *must* be part of a list.

In Quirks mode (which you get when you fail to supply a Doctype), browsers apply CSS that looks something like this:

```
/* Quirk: make orphaned LIs have inside bullet (b=1049) */

/* force inside position for orphaned lis */
li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

/* restore outside position for lists inside LIs */
li ul, li ol, li dir, li menu {
  list-style-position: outside;
}

/* undo previous two rules for properly nested lists */
  ul ul,   ul ol,   ul dir,   ul menu,   ul li,
  ol ul,   ol ol,   ol dir,   ol menu,   ol li,
 dir ul,  dir ol,  dir dir,  dir menu,  dir li,
menu ul, menu ol, menu dir, menu menu, menu li {
  list-style-position: inherit;
}
```

[source](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/quirk.css)

---

You *could* include that CSS in your stylesheet so it gets applied even in standards mode, but you *should* fix your markup and write valid HTML.

While you are at it, you should probably look at writing more semantic HTML. If you have a series of things with a name, an edit link, and a delete link … then your data is more tabular than listy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with the DOCTYPE capitalised and the list items within an unordered list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li>Title - <a href='#'>[Edit]</a> | <a href='#'>[Delete]</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have had similar issues in the past when using a lowercase `<!doctype html>`, but never had the same issues with `<!DOCTYPE html>`