# Importance of Doctype in HTML

Tags: html

In modern HTML, is there a purpose to having a Doctype tag to start an HTML page?  I'm wondering because when I add or remove it, nothing changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076432/why-do-i-need-a-doctype-what-does-it-do

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It helps the browser render the code correctly.