# AngularJS Material cards with flex layout overlap

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angularjs-material

I have a page with some AngularJS Material cards that need to be arranged in two columns. The last card should show with the full width below the two columns. However, card #3 and #4 (depending on the width) overlap with the final card. I have spent hours debugging this but just cannot find out why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```js
    angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']).controller('ctrl', function() {});
```

```html
<!-- Angular Material Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">

<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.5.9/angular-locale_de-de.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-cloak>

    <form name="couponform" novalidate>

        <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row">

            <div flex="auto" flex-gt-sm="60">

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card left #1</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card left #2</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card left #3</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card left #4</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

            </div>

            <div flex="auto" flex-gt-sm="40">

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card right</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

            </div>

        </div>

        <md-card>

            <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Card below</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>

            <md-card-content>
                <p>This should be below everything else</p>
            </md-card-content>

            <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                <md-button ng-click="submit()">Buchen</md-button>
            </md-card-actions>

        </md-card>

    </form>

</div>
```

Here is the relevant part of the output:

[image]

Actually, if you run the code here it comes out as expected, but if it's a separate HTML file, it does not. Very strange.

Comment: Noone can answer, perhaps it is an Angular Material bug...?

Comment: No happening for me on Chrome, what browser/version?

Comment: Did you copy the HTML to a file and open it in Chrome? I use v54.0.2840.100.

Comment: I did just now and it still works - Chrome 55.

Comment: Hmmm, pretty sure this happens when  `<!doctype html>` is missing.

Comment: @kuhnroyal Thank you so much, this is the solution! If you post this as an answer, you will get my bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `<!DOCTYPE html>`, without this the browser is rendering the page in quirks mode.

See [Why do I need a doctype? (What does it do)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076432/why-do-i-need-a-doctype-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 0):

I've created [**this**](http://codepen.io/divyanshu013/pen/BpQeYm) codepen for the snippet and it seems to be working fine even if width is changed to anything.

This could probably be a browser issue, doesn't seems like an Angular material bug.

```js
    angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']).controller('ctrl', function() {});
```

```html
<!-- Angular Material Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">

<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.5.9/angular-locale_de-de.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-cloak>

    <form name="couponform" novalidate>

        <div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row">

            <div flex="auto" flex-gt-sm="60">

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card left #1</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card left #2</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card left #3</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card left #4</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

            </div>

            <div flex="auto" flex-gt-sm="40">

                <md-card>

                    <md-card-title>
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <span class="md-headline">Card right</span>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>

                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                        <p>Some content</p>
                    </md-card-content>

                </md-card>

            </div>

        </div>

        <md-card>

            <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Card below</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>

            <md-card-content>
                <p>This should be below everything else</p>
            </md-card-content>

            <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                <md-button ng-click="submit()">Buchen</md-button>
            </md-card-actions>

        </md-card>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see any changes in your Codepen, and if you save the HTML to a file and open it in Chrome, the overlap issue is still there.