# object.onunload does not work properly in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, onunload

I was wondering why my codes works fine in chrome but it won't work in IE. I believe object.onunload works in IE too.

```js
function showPopup() {
  myPopup = window.open("", "", "dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:500px");
  myPopup.onunload = function() {
    alert("Your popup has been closed.");
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:showPopup();">Click me for popup</a>
```

Comment: Behaves as expected in IE11 for me - what version are you using?

Comment: Emulation suggests it only "doesn't work" in 7 & 8 - but you shouldn't be supporting these.

Comment: @Emissary I tested IE 5 up to Edge but it won't work. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Is your browser in quirks mode or compatibility mode?

Comment: I change ie versions in F12

Comment: Okay but there isn't an issue with the code you've posted, it's either an issue with the document or your environment - all I can suggest is make sure your document has an appropriate [doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076432) and for sanity, if you're working locally [disable intranet compatibility view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557299).