# Incoherent HTML behavior in relation with DOCTYPE

Tags: css, html

This piece of code executes *appropriately*:

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html>
<head>
<style>
#banner
{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 48px;
background: black;
color: white;
font-size: 24px;
text-align: center;
}

#mainTitle
{
position: fixed;
top:48;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 88px;
font-size: 56px;
text-align: center;
background-color: navajowhite;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: salmon;
}

#myBody
{
height:600px;
background-color: yellow;
}

#mainContainer
{
margin: 120px auto;/**/
width: 975px;
padding: 30px;
background-color: pink;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner">My Title</div>
<div id="mainTitle">My main title</div>
<div id="mainContainer">
<div id="myBody">Everything here in myBody</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now if you **de-comment-out** the DOCTYPE declaration it executes incoherently (using either Netbeans 8.2 or Smultron 'View' command). This behaviour is thus clearly related to the HTML5 header.

What is the matter, here?

Note: I am sorry this piece of code is not up on Fiddler. Nevertheless it should be very easy to test is 'as is' by pasting it into a new file using Netbeans and invoking the 'View' command.

Comment: I see no difference with or without Doctype. http://scratchpad.io/panoramic-boys-6672

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076432/why-do-i-need-a-doctype-what-does-it-do

Comment: The fact that `top:48;` works in Quirks Mode is a quirk. In standards mode it's just an error. Fix the error by adding `px`.

Comment: @Mr Lister — your solution is quite correct, indeed ! If you give as an Answer and not as a comment, I will vote it up.

Comment: @Thomas Byy — Not really. Thank you by the way. See the very interesting answer/comment by Mr Lister.

Comment: @BriceCoustillas Since this was a problem caused by a simple typo, it will not be necessary to keep the question around. You had a problem, it was solved, done. Only questions that are useful for future visitors need answers.