# Why and how to use <!DOCTYPE>?

Tags: html, doctype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's up, Doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414891/whats-up-doctype)
>   [HTML: What is the functionality of !DOCTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818587/html-what-is-the-functionality-of-doctype)

Okay, when I first learn HTML, I basically learn from trial and error as I went along, and didn't really sit down to properly learn it as far as I can remember. As a result of this, I've missed out a lot, and therefore, I've decided to start from the basics for my own benefit. :) So here I am, (re-)learning HTML.

Now, my question - the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag confuses me more than any other HTML tag I've ever come across, so I've come here to clear up any questions I have regarding it so I can use it confidently. :)

Firstly, can someone explain to me why it's necessary to use a `<!DOCTYPE>` tag in your webpages? They work fine without them, don't they? I've read that it is so it can be validated against the standards of the W3C, but that's all I know. A little more detail would be appreciated. :)

Secondly, after reading up on it, I'm still confused as to what exactly goes in my `<!DOCTYPE>` and how to type it out. For example, this is one kind of DOCTYPE I've seen used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Yet I've also seen other variations, and from what I've read, there are different DOCTYPES to validate against - it's all so very confusing, which should I use in my webpages if I was going to use one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W3C has a pretty good answer to this at http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

> Why?
>
> Why specify a doctype? Because it defines which version of (X)HTML
>   your document is actually using, and this is a critical piece of
>   information needed by some tools processing the document.
>
> For example, specifying the doctype of your document allows you to use
>   tools such as the Markup Validator to check the syntax of your
>   (X)HTML. Such tools won't be able to work if they do not know what
>   kind of document you are using.
>
> But the most important thing is that with most families of browsers, a
>   doctype declaration will make a lot of guessing unnecessary, and will
>   thus trigger a "standard" rendering mode.

Basically if you leave it out, the browser will try and guess what rendering mode to use, and it might cause some unexpected results.

Comment: Non-standard rendering or webpages is called "Quirks mode" by the way

Answer (score 2):

it basically tells the browser how to interpret the page you're sending it. If you don't send anything, it has to make guesses. Some constructs are valid in a format while invalid in others, etc.  Some browsers may display your page correctly while others don't.  So yes, do choose and send a DOCTYPE.

There are several doctypes you can use, xhtml, html strict, html transitional, 4.01, etc. You can see a list of valid types here ... http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Answer (score 0):

The  declaration refers to a Document Type Definition (DTD). A DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

Going forward, for html5 compliance, the correct tag is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You set a doctype  to say to your browser or somthing else what you going tho do. Its look  like what you do whit a business card

There are several doctype's. The most yoused doctype's are transitional:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD        XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/ xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The some stricter doctype is: (see "strict")

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Also you can youse a speciffie doctype declaraition for youse a frameset. But this is outdated, frameset is a unnecessary for my but i will show you the doctype for this. But forgot the framesets this is an not useful html element whit html5. Here see you the follow frameset doctype:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">

And at last. You can youse a language attribuut for your the doctypes. This can youse by html and xhtml.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```