# Is it safe to remove the <DOCTYPE ...> in post-IE area?

Tags: doctype

Is it safe to remove the `<DOCTYPE ...>` in post-IE area?

I don't need to support IE or other outdated browsers.

I could not find anything about this topic here: https://caniuse.com/

BTW: I don't trust any blog article or Stackoverflow answer which is from 2019 or older for this question. Today we don't need to support IE, this was different in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is <!doctype html> required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37959963/11683)

Comment: [Link to the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype) for reference. I think this is really one of those "Conventionally it should be there, but in practice it won't make much difference", but it will be interesting to see if anyone knows of any problems when skipping it in a modern browser.

Comment: @DBS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types

Comment: @GSerg I don't trust any blog article or Stackoverflow answer which is from 2019 or older for this question. Today we don't need to support IE, this was different in the past.

Comment: @guettli "All browsers need the doctype" does not involve IE. The quirks mode and the almost-standard mode did not go anywhere.

Comment: Then read the standard if older posts and articles don't do it for you. A doctype is *required* and you will be in a world of constant problems without one.