# What is the necessity of <!DOCTYPE html> tag and what will happen if it is not present in the code?

Tags: html, doctype

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag must be present at the beginning of an HTML document. Can I know the reason why? Also, I've noticed that my webpage works all fine even without this tag.

Here is a sample code along with the tag.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Hello, world!
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code without the tag.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Hello, world!
</body>
</html>
```

Both of the codes return the same result. What is the actual purpose of the tag and what will happen if it is not present in an HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the  tag.

The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

In HTML 4.01, the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration refers to a DTD, because HTML 4.01 was based on SGML. The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

`HTML5` is not based on SGML, and therefore does not require a reference to a DTD.

[source](http://w3schools.com)
DTD-Document Type Definition.

also take look at previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818587/what-is-the-functionality-of-doctype)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've to know doctype declaration is not a tag, but an instructor that tells the browser which version of html you are using or you want use.
In HTML 4.01 doctype declaration refers DTD, The DTD define complete rules for the mark up languages because HTML 4.01 based on SGML.
Html 5 or current version of html does not require the doctype declaration because it does not based on SGML.
But its better always to add the Doctype declaration to your html document so that the browser will understand which type html expect to.