# Why does an HTML document require both <!DOCTYPE> and <html> tags? Couldn't these both serve the same purpose?

Tags: html

I don't understand why these are separated. They both seem to do the same thing...declare that the document is an HTML document.

Edit: This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818587/what-is-the-functionality-of-doctype) because I'm not asking what the functionality of  is, I understand that. I'm wondering why HTML was designed to separate those two tags. Or why HTML even needs , since the  implies that the whole document is an HTML document, and I'm not *aware* of anything that would go after .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the functionality of !DOCTYPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818587/what-is-the-functionality-of-doctype)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> specifies that the following document will be a version of HTML. HTML5 is the standard for <!DOCTYPE html>. <html></html> is where the actual content for the document will exist. Technically, neither are *required* but highly recommended. Many browsers like Chrome can parse and run HTML even without the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE>` provides information of the **HTML version** of the document.

`<html>` tag:

- tells browser it is `HTML`
- `root` of the document
- `container` of all other tags, except `<!DOCTYPE>`

Comment: So theoretically, you could declare a non-html document with an html version if there were some kind of alternative to <html>?